# How can I create/update a session variable from a service object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-variables

From the controller, I can create/update a session variable.

```
def action
  ...
  session[:var] = "success"
end
```

When I call a service object from the same controller action, the same line of code does not work to update the same session variable within the service object.

```
def action
  ...
  ServiceObject.new(@user).write
end
```

I receive this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<ServiceObject:########>
```

Why? Is there a way to update a session variable from within a service object? I would like to do this so that the session variable will reflect the state of the service object depending on what is running.

Comment: I would advise against trying to access the session from anything other than the controller, it's breaks mvc. What specifically are you trying to accomplish by storing state in the session?

Comment: I would like to to use a session variable to store a service object method's status; so the variable's value would be updated depending on the status. I thought this would be a simple way to keep track of the status of a service object which takes a while to run, and is running in the background using delayed_job. Ultimately, my goal is to notify the user when the service object has completed its method.

Comment: Could you store the service objects job id and look manually look up the status of the job? You could also potentially create a record in the database backing the service object or a `Job` of some sort and store that id in the session and occasionally fetch and check the status property of the db record.

Comment: Thank you @CWitty, I'm sorry I didn't follow up sooner. I ended up giving the object a job_id attribute and updating that, and occasionally checking like you said. No session variables needed. Feel free to write your comment in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I added that as an aswer @LeoBrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you store the service objects job id and look manually look up the status of the job? You could also potentially create a record in the database backing the service object or a Job of some sort and store that id in the session and occasionally fetch and check the status property of the db record.